# API or template folder redirect in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a directory structure as follows:

```
.htaccess
api.php
template/index.html
```

When calling `domain.com/api/someendpoint`, the request is forwarded to `api.php`.

```sh
# enable apache rewrite engine
RewriteEngine on
# Deliver the folder or file directly if it exists on the server
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Push every request to api.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA]
```

now, when calling `domain.com`, the request should be called to the `index.html` in the template directory:

```sh
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^$
RewriteRule . template/index.html [QSA]
```

this does not work, the directoryListening is always displayed.

What is the correct way to get the `index.html`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^$
> RewriteRule . template/index.html [QSA]
> ```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* (ie. `.`) unnecessarily matches *everything* except the document root. And the `REQUEST_URI` server variable always starts with a slash, so the *condition* will never match anyway. So, basically, the rule is doing nothing

To rewrite just the root then you just need a single rule in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^$ template/index.html [L]
```

Ideally, this would go *before* your existing rewrites for your API, although it doesn't strictly matter since the other rewrites do not rewrite the root directory (because of the restrictive conditions).

> ```
> # Push every request to api.php
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA]
> ```

Should *everything* really be sent to `api.php`, or perhaps just URLs that start `/api/`, as in your example? At the very least, you should be using the `+` quantifier, not `*`, since you want to exclude requests for the document root (currently, the 3rd condition is blocking requests to the document root from being rewritten).

Note that if your URLs are of the form `/api/someendpoint` and you are rewriting to `/api.php` then you need to ensure that MultiViews is disabled at the top of the `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
```